# Why is my unique-sort function raising IndexError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, unique, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to debug this and I cannot see how to make it work.

```
def makeUnique(numList):

    """Takes in a list of numbers, sorts them, and then removes duplicate numbers, modifying the input list."""

    numList.sort() # making sure that numList is taken as a list.
    i = 0
    while i < (len(numList)):
        if numList == numList[i+1]: #I'm sure this is where the problem is.
            del numList[i+1]
        else:
            i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually have two problems, but you're right about where the first one is. This line:

```
        if numList == numList[i+1]:
```

… is testing whether the *whole* of `numList` is equal to the `i+1`th element of it, which obviously is never true. It should look like this:

```
        if numList[i] == numList[i+1]:
```

… which tests whether the `i`th element is equal to the `i+1`th element, as you want.

Your second problem is that, the last time round your `for` loop, there are `i+1` elements in your list - but `numList[i+1]` in your `if` statement tries to find an element *after* the last one (because of Python's [zero-based indexing](http://python-history.blogspot.cl/2013/10/why-python-uses-0-based-indexing.html)) – and you get an error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If you replace the line:

```
    while i < (len(numList)):
```

with

```
    while i < (len(numList) - 1):
```

… you'll loop one less time, and avoid falling off the end of the list.

Fixing both those problems, you end up with this:

```
def makeUnique(numList):        
    numList.sort()
    i = 0
    while i < (len(numList) - 1):
        if numList[i] == numList[i+1]:
            del numList[i+1]
        else:
            i = i + 1
```

… which works as expected:

```
>>> s = [82, 101, 112, 101, 116, 105, 116, 105, 111, 117, 115]
>>> makeUnique(s)
>>> s
[82, 101, 105, 111, 112, 115, 116, 117]
```